# Delphi XE2 on iOS with Indy or Third Party Internet Components

Tags: ios, delphi, rest, indy, firemonkey

Are there third party components available for Delphi XE2 to create iOS applications with Internet support?

For example, the Indy components that ship with Delphi XE2 do not work with a FireMonkey iOS app. I want to be able to communicate with a REST Web Service in my iOS app.

Comment: The Indy components are not "useless". They don't work yet on iOS, maybe. They certainly work on FireMonkey Win32/Win64 apps, and on OSX apps. Bad-mouthing the entire project because it doesn't work on a single,  **newly supported** platform is simply rude and insulting to the people who have spent years working on it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Delphi XE2 FireMonkey support Indy for cross-platform apps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365421/does-delphi-xe2-firemonkey-support-indy-for-cross-platform-apps)

Comment: Ken: Indy mostly work iOS. Just not with FM apparently

Comment: I certainly did not intend to bad mouth the Indy project. I love the Indy components. I have been using them for years on Win32. What I do not understand is why Embarcadero releases Delphi XE and saying that you can do iOS applications. Yes, you can but only if you use Firemonkey and none of the other important components. Today, iPhone and iPad applications need to be able to communicate to a backend. That fact that the Indy components are not supported with Firemonkey and iOS, is frustrating. That's why I wanted to see if anyone knows any third party components.

Comment: Marco: Indy works with iOS? Can you elaborate a little on that?

Comment: Delphi XE2 was released with full notification that you had to use FireMonkey for cross-platform applications. See the [Features Matrix](http://www.embarcadero.com/delphi-features-matrix). Also, because iOS is *supported* doesn't mean you'll have full-blown capability. Delphi XE supports Win32 applications, but doesn't give you wrappers for 100% of the API, and to expect what is basically iOS support 1.0 to provide everything is simply unreasonable. And your original comment said "Indy is worthless" (exact words, because I removed them).

Comment: Indy will eventually work in iOS, just not yet through lack of time. Like all things, you just need to wait a while. iOS suuport was originally not going to be in the initial XE2 release so it is very new at this stage, and things will definitely improve over time.

Comment: I saw a report on direct usage on iOS with FPC (so without firemonkey and a XE2 generated XCode template), and that had problems with DNS resolving. That is pretty much what I wanted to share, see the first answer. Specially since I didn't expect that many quality answers since it is all so new.

Answer (score 0):

On FPC lists, people complain that the resolving doesn't work properly on iOS, but that the base sockets do work. The question is probably where iOS differs from OS X wrt resolving of DNS names.

I assume something similar is going on with the FPC in  under XE2, but am not entirely sure since FM is not VCL, and the event pump might be different which could create additional problems.

Anyway, if you can get it compiled, try with only IPs as host to see if it is a general problem, or the relatively simple DNS resolving biut.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question, which is in the first paragraph. The asker is aware of Indy. Your post should at best be a comment to the original question. :)

Comment: Then the answer is no. There is no XE2 compiler for iOS, there is just an export in the IDE to an XCode/Free Pascal project to my best knowledge. And my answer is about Indy and iOS. He didn't say that it had to be Firemonkey :-)

Comment: The final paragraph specifically mentions "FireMonkey iOS", and the question is about XE2 iOS apps. How does that not indicate that it has to work with FireMonkey? (Note I didn't downvote; I just question whether or not this should be defined as an answer.)

Comment: "by example" does not indicate an exclusive choice. Anyway, I don't want to bicker about this; I'm not a lawyer so I don't enjoy that. You took it one way, I another. Soit.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Real Thin Client has support you need:  http://www.realthinclient.com/

Win32 with Delphi 6 - XE; Win32+Win64+MacOSX+iOS with RAD Studio / Delphi XE2