# Delphi XE2 Firemonkey File Download?

Tags: delphi, download, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

How can i download a file over a url in firemonkey that is compatible in both Windows and MacOS X? the download should be over https.

Comment: Indy supports Windows and OSX, so try using the `TIdHTTP` component , btw the internet is full of samples about how use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Indy that's supplied with XE2 supports Mac OSX.
See: [Does Delphi XE2 FireMonkey support Indy for cross-platform apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365421/does-delphi-xe2-firemonkey-support-indy-for-cross-platform-apps)

Here's the workflow:

```
File-> New (Firemonkey HD app)
Add Mac OSX as target platform
Place a TIdHTTP component on the form
Place a TEdit on the form
```

The following code should get some rudimentary results

```
type
  TForm16 = class(TForm)
    IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    procedure Edit1Enter(Sender: TObject);
  public
    MyFile: TFileStream;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm16.Edit1Enter(Sender: TObject);
var
  Success: boolean;
begin
  if (MyFile = nil) then try
    //Correct path handling to be added
    //filename should be extracted from the url etc etc.
    MyFile:= TFileStream.Create('Test.dat',fmCreate);
    Success:= true;
  except
    Success:= false;
  end;
  if Success then begin
    IdHTTP1.Get(Edit1.Text, MyFile);
    //do stuff with the file
  end;
end;
```

One word of advise, make sure it works with `http` first, `https` can be tricky to setup.
Also make sure you have the latest version of Indy installed and the latest XE2 updates.